# How do I get my subclass of UIView to appear in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to share as much code between my common UIViews as possible by subclassing UIView.

Is there a way to make this UIView accessable in Interface Builder?

What's the best way to reuse hand-coded UIViews in Cocoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make your custom views available in interface builder permanently, you could create a plugin for interface builder.

See here:
[How do you display custom UIViews in InterfaceBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494520/how-do-you-display-custom-uiviews-in-interfacebuilder)

Answer (score 3):

Add a normal UIView to your window/view in interface builder and in the Identity Inspector, change the name of the class to your UIView subclass.