# Custom UIView built with Interface Builder accessible/positionable via Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

This shouldn't be this confusing.  I have a custom UIView with a bunch on controls on it.  UILabels, buttons, etc.  I've created this Nib using Interface Builder.  I want to be able to position this custom uiview on another UIView using the interface builder.

How do I link my UIView custom class, to the nib?  initWithCoder gets called, but I want this class to get loaded from the nib.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found an acceptable answer? Please mark it, thanks.

Comment: @JoePasq do you see ANY valid answers here?

Comment: i actually never got this working unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, you have to create a plug-in for Interface Builder that uses your custom control's class. As soon as you create and install your plug-in, you will be able to add by drag and drop, instances of your view onto another window or view in Interface Builder. To learn about creating IB Plugins, see the [Interface Builder Plug-In Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the chapter on creating your own IB Palette controls from Aaron Hillegass's book, [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321503619).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34218/jason-coco) is the link to the original author of the accepted answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494520/how-do-you-display-custom-uiviews-in-interfacebuilder).

Comment: It turns out this is not supported as of XCode 4.0+

Answer (score 2):

You only need to make a plugin if you want the custom view to draw correctly in the nib you are using it.  You can make a custom control and then have it show as a blank rectangle until instantiated during run right now.

[How do I get a view in Interface Builder to load a custom view in another nib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944964/how-do-i-get-a-view-in-interface-builder-to-load-a-custom-view-in-another-nib)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `UIViewController` object using Interface Builder, and then set the `UIViewController`'s "Nib name" property.
I don't know if this messes up your model, but I think it's the only way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Kenny, thanks for the quick response.  I just tried that.  I added a UIViewController to my main view, set it's nib name to custom sub view's nib, and connected the uiviewcontroller's view property to the custom view in interface builder.  Same thing.  It's just not showing up.  initWithCoder is getting called on the custom view, but nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

In IB bring up the Identity Inspector tool (Command-4) then select your custom view and in the Class pop-up choose the name of your custom class instead of generic UIView. You may want to connect it to an ivar as well. In your ViewController declare an instance of your custom class with an `IBOutlet` in front of it. Then go back and bring up the Connections Inspector and connect your view to the ivar by click-dragging from the custom-view's referencing outlet to the File's Owner (which should be an instance of your ViewController) and choosing the ivar name.

When your NIB is loaded it should be creating an object of that type and connecting it to that variable.