# Adding custom control on a UIViewControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have created Empty control - LogonErrorMessage.xib. In interface builder placed there a View control and inside it placed a label - kind of created custom message control.

Then i created Objective-C class that is named also LogonErrorMessage.h and LogonErrorMessage.m.

Then in LogonErrorMessage.xib i selected View control and in "Custom class" section changed class to LogonErrorMessage, to tie the *.xib to class.

Now i'm trying to do this on my MainViewController:

```
LogonErrorMessage *logonError = [[LogonErrorMessage alloc] init];
logonError.iboMessageText.text = message;
logonError.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 307, 100);
[self.view addSubview:logonError];
```

And the message control doesn't show up - what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subviews for custom UIView with Nib (.xib) don't load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137846/subviews-for-custom-uiview-with-nib-xib-dont-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your first line:

```
LogonErrorMessage *logonError = [[LogonErrorMessage alloc] init];
```

With

```
//Loads all views named "MyView", in your case, replace "MyView" with your xib name.
NSArray *allCustomViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LogonErrorMessage" owner:self options:nil];

//Assuming there's only one MyView.xib
LogonErrorMessage* customView = [allCustomViews firstObject];
```

Comment: No visible interface declares the selector

Comment: Oh wait, thought LogonErrorMessage was a view controller. Editing.