# Does iOS support nested custom subviews created with independent .xib files?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

It doesn't seem possible to create nested custom subviews using .xib's created with Interface Builder. For example I want to create a custom `BarView` and nested inside of that a custom `FooView` where the contents of each view is created in IB and stored in
a .xib file:

[image]

The `BarView` is loaded from its .xib file and added as a subview in the `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var barView : BarView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.barView = 
          (UINib(nibName: "BarView", bundle:Bundle.main).
             instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? BarView)
        self.view.addSubview(self.barView!)
    }
}
```

I can create and connect to an outlet for the `UIButton` created by IB:

```
class BarView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NSLog("BarView init:NSCoder, barButton set: \(barButton != nil)")
    }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        NSLog("BarView: awakeFromNib(), barButton set: \(barButton != nil)")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIButton!    
}
```

I can can also connect outlets and actions to the nest `FooView`:

```
class FooView: UIView {

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       NSLog("FooView init:NSCoder, fooButton set: \(fooButton != nil)")
   }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        NSLog("FooView: awakeFromNib(), fooButton set: \(fooButton != nil)")
    }

    @IBAction func doFoo(_ sender: Any) {
        NSLog("doFoo")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var fooButton: UIButton!
}
```

I can see the `init?(NSCoder)` and `awakeFromNib()` methods are indeed being called. I don't know why `BarView`'s method are called
twice:

```
... BarView  init:NSCoder, barButton set: false
... BarView: awakeFromNib(), barButton set: false
... FooView init:NSCoder, fooButton set: false
... BarView init:NSCoder, barButton set: false
... BarView: awakeFromNib(), barButton set: true
... FooView: awakeFromNib(), fooButton set: false
```

The contents of the `FooView` (i.e. the `fooButton`) does not show up and is `nil` in the `FooView` both callbacks. Is nesting custom view's created with independent .xib files supported? If so, what is the trick to accomplishing this?

The various suggestions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137846/subviews-for-custom-uiview-with-nib-xib-dont-load) are not quite right or don't work.

Comment: Are you trying to make this `@IBDesignable` so you can see the UI elements in Storyboard? Or, are you just trying to get them working at run-time?

Comment: That would be nice, but I would like to start by having all the elements added as proper sub views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't seem possible to create nested custom subviews using .xib's created with Interface Builder.

Bear in mind that you're swimming against the current here; storyboards were introduced exactly to get away from having lots of separate .xib files.

> I can see the init?(NSCoder) and awakeFromNib() methods are indeed being called. I don't know why BarView's method are called twice

They're called twice because you're creating two instances. One is in `Main.storyboard`, and the other is in `BarView.xib`.

> The contents of the FooView (i.e. the fooButton) does not show up and is nil in the FooView both callbacks

This sounds like it's probably another case of mistaken identity, similar to the problem above. There's an instance of `Foo` in `BarView.xib` that's different from the one in `FooView.xib`.

> Is nesting custom view's created with independent .xib files supported? If so, what is the trick to accomplishing this?

Not directly, as far as I remember. You can certainly load a view from a .xib file and add it to your view graph, though. You could even create a `UIView` subclass whose job is to load the view in a specified .xib and set it as its own subview. One thing you'll want to pay attention to is the *File's Owner* proxy object in the .xib file; be sure to understand how you can use it to connect objects in your .xib file to outlets in the file's owner.

Comment: This whole experiment was born out of trying to decipher another codebase that was using this pattern (that is why I am swimming against the current). Your explanations of why `init` and `awakeFromNib` being called twice was correct -- I removed `BarView` from the storyboard and load it programmatically and now they are only called once. `FooView` is being loaded, but the connection to its button is not being set. I'll try loading it programmatically as well in either `BarView`'s init(NSCoder)` or `awakeFromNib`.  Which would be better?

Comment: You’ll want to use awakeFromNib for that — you want to be sure the whole view graph is constructed before you try to connect things to it. Be sure to specify the file’s owner when you load the xib so that objects in the xib can connect to the owner’s outlets.

Comment: Thanks -- I followed your advice and its all working. I get the annoying "your `fooButton` is not key-value compliant" but I did the usual delete and reset outliets and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly ***possible*** to embed `FooView.xib` in `BarView.xib` -- the bigger question, though, is: **why**?

Here's a quick example...

**FooView.xib**

[image]

**FooView.xib source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="FooView" customModule="BarFooXIBs" customModuleProvider="target"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="scQ-53-cS2">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="165"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9Gm-YT-3U5">
                    <rect key="frame" x="80" y="65.5" width="160" height="34"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="160" id="5ue-te-ayT"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Foo Button"/>
                    <state key="highlighted">
                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="btnTap:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="acw-XK-os0"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="eoT-BN-I0x"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="9Gm-YT-3U5" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="scQ-53-cS2" secondAttribute="centerX" id="7jV-qQ-R9k"/>
                <constraint firstItem="9Gm-YT-3U5" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="scQ-53-cS2" secondAttribute="centerY" id="UOQ-gZ-0ew"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="354.375" y="445.625"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBlueColor">
            <color red="0.0" green="0.47843137254901963" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

**BarView.xib**

[image]

**BarView.xib source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="BarView" customModule="BarFooXIBs" customModuleProvider="target"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="heW-ya-dwr">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="336"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4PF-6J-JzA">
                    <rect key="frame" x="40" y="20" width="240" height="34"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                    <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Bar Button"/>
                    <state key="highlighted">
                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="btnTap:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="lzM-kB-YyV"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SRX-fO-B8d" customClass="FooView" customModule="BarFooXIBs" customModuleProvider="target">
                    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="74" width="280" height="242"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="hy0-ij-uLz"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="SRX-fO-B8d" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="4PF-6J-JzA" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="95H-Gc-glY"/>
                <constraint firstItem="4PF-6J-JzA" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hy0-ij-uLz" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="SvQ-5U-H90"/>
                <constraint firstItem="SRX-fO-B8d" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hy0-ij-uLz" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="Syg-Rc-Uw8"/>
                <constraint firstItem="hy0-ij-uLz" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="SRX-fO-B8d" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="iAU-bn-oAu"/>
                <constraint firstItem="4PF-6J-JzA" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hy0-ij-uLz" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="mjS-As-tx9"/>
                <constraint firstItem="hy0-ij-uLz" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="SRX-fO-B8d" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="pYK-Yb-uk1"/>
                <constraint firstItem="hy0-ij-uLz" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="4PF-6J-JzA" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="tMQ-Ka-JDb"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="120" y="70"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemRedColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.23137254901960785" blue="0.18823529411764706" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Storyboard source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina5_9" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="BarFooXIBs" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="812"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ixt-jj-akZ" customClass="BarView" customModule="BarFooXIBs" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="84" width="295" height="240"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="240" id="YsU-Yu-Czr"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Ixt-jj-akZ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="Zi8-LJ-vJH"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Ixt-jj-akZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="40" id="qx9-u2-f4a"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Ixt-jj-akZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="tar-CY-7ai"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="43" y="118"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemGreenColor">
            <color red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.7803921568627451" blue="0.34901960784313724" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

**Couple "helper" extensions**

```
public protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {
    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self) // defaults to the name of the class implementing this protocol.
    }
    static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }
    func setupFromNib() {
        guard let view = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
}

extension NSObject {
    var className: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
    class var className: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

**FooView class**

```
class FooView: UIView, NibLoadable {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        setupFromNib()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: Any) {
        print(#function, "in", self.className)
    }
}
```

**BarView class**

```
class BarView: UIView, NibLoadable {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        setupFromNib()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: Any) {
        print(#function, "in", self.className)
    }

}
```

---

When running, it looks like this:

[image]

Tapping either button will call the `@IBAction` func (in the associated class) and output to the debug console:

```
btnTap(_:) in BarView
btnTap(_:) in FooView
```

Note that we can replicate that via code, rather than Storyboard.

This, with an empty view controller, will give you the exact same result:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let bar = BarView()
        bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bar.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        view.addSubview(bar)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            bar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            bar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            bar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
        ])
    }

}
```

We ***can*** mark these as `@IBDesignable` -- however, from my experience, Xcode is pretty sketchy when it comes to that. Frequently get *"error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for UIView..."*

As a general rule, embedding a xib in a xib in a xib etc is just asking for trouble. You end up with absurdly tightly coupled elements which will be prone to errors.

If you have a legitimate reason for doing so, great, it's your code / project.

Comment: Thanks -- I completely agree with your assessment. I was trying to understand someone else's codebase  that did something like this. I have a love/hate relationship w IB -- I love the visual layout tools (I have been a MacOS programmer since the inception of OS X and it has evolved a lot), but when something is wrong in the storyboard/xib it is hard to debug. I tend to do as much as I can programatically nowadays.

Comment: The problem of your solution is you need to override `init` methods in each class manually. A solution with subclassing exists when you just need to subclass a specific view