# Adding custom objects to object library

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

How do I add custom objects to the custom object library in xcode?

I created a class myObject and I want this new object to appear in my object library list for use with IB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but if your custom object is a subclass of something else, e.g. `NSObject` or `UIView`, etc, then you can simply select the parent object and then change the identity to your subclass with the attributes window.

If you want a direct answer, then read this post: [How do you display custom UIViews in InterfaceBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494520/how-do-you-display-custom-uiviews-in-interfacebuilder) for instructions to create a plug-in for Interface Builder that uses your custom class.

Comment: that's not an answer, and link direct to no answer as well

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4 doesn't support IB plug-ins anymore. You're out of luck.
(This is a direct quote from a comment of one of the answers to [How do you display custom UIViews in InterfaceBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494520/how-do-you-display-custom-uiviews-in-interfacebuilder))