# Is it possible to add my custom control to xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

While writing snippets of code. i have got an idea to create my own control which will help me a lot. I know how to create a custom control.

**Question**

Is it possible to add my custom control to XCode. and wherever i like i just drag it in .xib file in any object as we do with snippets.

After adding it to XCode . It must behave like other controls . we can create IBOutlets and Action of Control.

Comment: No this is not possible... You have to use your custom control using your class

Answer (score 0):

you need to create interface builder plugin . Perhaps the post "[Adding custom objects to object library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016414/adding-custom-objects-to-object-library)" is a good reference related to your need.