# Create and use Custom Views from a Framework in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Do you know of any good information/tutorial on how to create and use Custom Controls from a framework - in Interface Builder.

Making the View show up in Interface Builders "Object Library"?
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add any `UIView` object in Interface Builder, and change it to the custom control type in the `Identity Inspector`

[image]

Whether or not it will look like a grey box, or something more descriptive is down to the Framework and whether it has implemented `@IBDesignable`.

For more information about `@IBDesignable`, have a look here: http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make it show up in the "Object Library"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016414/adding-custom-objects-to-object-library

Comment: The plugin process referred to in the link you provided in the comments doesn't exist anymore. Still looking for how to make a custom object show in the Object Library!