# How to Create Custom Controls in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, long-press, touch-up-inside

I want to create a new `Control` which is the combination of two `UIImageViews`  and one `UILabel`. I need to implement `TouchUpInsite` and `LongPress` event for the entire `Control`. I mean the action would perform for any `UIImageView` or `UILabel` in the entire `Control`.

So, how to create this `Control` in `objective-c` and reuse it like other default `Controls` in  `iOS`?

Comment: What have your tried? There seems to me that you have put any effort in solving this yourself. There are many tutorial on how to create custom controls online.

Comment: I have seen Tutorials, where they are Creating Custom Classes and assigning these Classes to the Control. But, I want to use the Control as a plugin, by which I can use the Customized Control in any project.

Comment: Still the same logic applies, you create your own control that inherits from `UIControl`. The amount of customization is up to you, the more properties you add the more it can be customized.

Comment: How to make that Control accessed from Object library?

Comment: You can't, please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494520/how-do-you-display-custom-uiviews-in-interfacebuilder

Comment: Also have look [`IBInspectable`/`IBDesignable`](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a View of type UICONTRol and add image and label as subview.

You can take IBACTION of this view and do what ever you want to do on touch up inside.

Comment: As I mentioned in comment, How to make that Control accessed from Object library? I studied somewhere we can create plugins before XCode-4. But now, I didn't find that feature.